# Fancybox, recarregar página anterior

Tags: fancybox

Estou trabalhando com o fancybox. Tudo está funcionando normalmente. Porém, eu preciso recarregar as informações na página anterior, ou seja, na página que tenho o botão que chama o fancybox.

A função que uso é esta:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#popup1,#popup2").fancybox({
                    'width'             : '100%',
                    'height'            : '100%',

                    'autoScale'         : false,
                    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                    'type'              : 'iframe',                        
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

o meu botão que chama é este:

```
<a id="popup1" href="cupomeletronico_prodrapido.php?&cod=<? echo $r[0]; ?>" class="laranja">CORRIGIR</a>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `onClosed` que vai recarregar a página anterior.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#popup1,#popup2").fancybox({
                    'width'             : '100%',
                    'height'            : '100%',

                    'autoScale'         : false,
                    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                    'type'              : 'iframe',

                    'onClosed': function() {   
                        self.location.reload(true); 
                    ;}
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

Sobre a documentação do fancybox confere [aqui](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado. É exatamente o que eu preciso. Muito obrigado!!!!!!